# SeviceStack Razor with SqlMembershipProvider authorization

Tags: razor, asp.net-membership, servicestack

Razor is nicely working under it's own api url

```
 <location path="api">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

but when SqlMembershipProvider authorization is added like so

```
 <location path="api">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
      </httpHandlers>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The api/urls are redirected to the regular web forms login page as expected but never successfully redirects back after a correct user/pass is entered.  The same login page works fine with the legacy .net .aspx locations in the app.

How do I configure SqlMembershipProvider to be run before my .cshtml pages so the User identity can be accessed via RequestContext.HttpContext.User as described in other articles?